# How to escape opening curly brace in Angular?

Tags: angular

How to escape the first opening curly brace below?

```html
<div>
    {
        <ng-container *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3,4]; let last=last">
            {{x}} 
            <ng-container *ngIf="!last">,</ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    }
</div>
```

The expected output: `{1,2,3,4}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{{ '{' }}` to escape it.

Comment: Correct, A simple StackBlitz rasied an 'Unexpected character' error with suggestion as yours

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I get your question right.

```
<div>
    <span ng-non-bindable>{</span>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3,4]; let last=last">
            {{x}} 
            <ng-container *ngIf="!last">,</ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    <span ng-non-bindable>}</span>
</div>
```

Output: `{1,2,3,4}`

If you are asking on how to escape the curly brace then the method is by using [interpolation syntax](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation)

UPDATE:

Use [`ngNonBindable`/`ng-non-bindable`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) depends on your angular version.

Comment: The output lacks of `{` and `}`.

Answer (score -1):

```
   ..some html above
    <ng-container *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3,4]; let last=last">
        {{x}} 
        <ng-container *ngIf="!last">,</ng-container>
    </ng-container>
   ..some html below
```

Comment: There is no need of a redundant surrounding div (which does nothing)